# Please, define symbols which are pointed

Tags: symbol

[image]

What do these symbols mean? Please, describe

[image]

It is a part of high voltage power supply

Comment: I'd hazard a guess on delta and star connections, but these things always work out better if you can at least tell the people here where you found these symbols.

Comment: Please, add more context, that is a  bigger part of the schematic and some explanation in words.

Comment: I added context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further context it is hard to tell exactly.

It seems a tri-phase transformer whose primary side is configured as an interconnected star, whereas you have two set of secondary windings, one configured as a delta connection and the other as a star connection.

See [this table](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/trans34.gif)